# 23.10 Failing To Boot Due To smbd service

Tags: boot, samba, 23.10

I am attempting to fix an issue with booting up my ubuntu OS, and have run out of ideas how to fix it

The issue I am seeing is that, as part of the Ubuntu boot, I see `[FAILED] Failed to start smbd.service - Samba SMD Daemon`. From there, the boot just hangs, and will sit there indefinitely. So far I've been unable to boot past it, but from a live cd have tried:

- Reverting the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to the default version in `/usr/share/samba/smb.conf`.
- Disabling the service by adding a `/etc/init/smbd.override` containing `manual`.
- Manually renaming the `/etc/init.d/smbd` file
- Deleting the registry at `/var/lib/samba/registry.tdb`

I really don't even know what else to try. Does anyone have any suggestions?